Using a dynamo hub to run ONLY rear lights
I have a trailer that I use regularly at night and I want to put some dynamo-powered lights on it.
I have an old Shimano DH-3N80 hub and was thinking of building a 16" wheel with it and getting power from that (one of the existing wheels is badly buckled anyway and since I have the hub laying about, I thought Why not?)
The problem I'm facing is that all dynamo lighting systems appear to run a rear light off of the front, which (I assume) has an inbuilt rectifier to deliver the DC to the lights. Has anyone tried this before? Are there rear lights out there that will run directly off of a dynamo (I guess using filament bulbs that will take the AC from the dynamo might work but can you still buy such lights!?).
Is it worth the effort? I've been stuck before with flat batteries, which is a problem -- I'd like to have something I don't have to think about once it's set up.

How many rear lights do you have for this project ?

Do you ever remove the wheels from the trailer for storage etc?  Do the wheels use Wheelchair mounts or something else ?

To answer these two questions, I'm yet to buy the lights, but I was thinking of mounting two at the back of the trailer and I don't tend to remove the wheels for storage. They attach with vertical 100mm dropouts (so perfect for my dynamo hub) with a safety washer thing that fits into a hole that stops them falling out if loose.

You could put a front light on your trailer ;-)

Ha, right. I did experiment with a front light on the front corner of the trailer just thinking that it might help illuminate the road ahead a bit better, but it was remarkably distracting. It just continually felt like there was someone about to overtake me!

Perhaps a bigger problem is that a 16" wheel will be spinning awfully fast, and that increases the open circuit output voltage of the dynamo.

The tiny power usage of most rear lights wouldn't be worth a dynamo in my opinion. Spare batteries are easy to carry and battery-powered has the benefit of having lights even when stopped.

@jpa Yes, in an ideal world, I would always have spare batteries in my pocket and wouldn't forget to turn off the lights when I got home :)

Yes, it will work just fine in this day and age of modern LED lighting.
A dynamo in its typical operating mode is a constant current device. It provides very high voltage, far higher than 6 volts, if running at speed. But it gives only 0.5 amperes, and with the typical filament bulbs (0.4 amperes / 6 volts front, 0.1 amperes / 6 volts rear), the voltage stabilizes to 6 volts.
It used to be the case that front bulbs needed to be chosen based on whether you have a rear light (if you have, 0.4 amperes, 6 volts, 2.4 watts; if not, 0.5 amperes, 6 volts, 3 watts). However, LED rear lights took less than 0.1 amperes of current, so a 3 watt bulb might be more appropriate with a LED rear light.
However, with modern LED lights, the LED has a switched mode power supply that provides the correct current, and handles whatever voltages the dynamo might create. It's true that without a front light, a rear light takes less than 0.1 amperes so the voltage rises far above 6 volts. But the LED drive circuitry should handle that.
I would find it very unlikely that a single LED rear light would be destroyed if you don't have a front light. I guess at a very high speed, the voltages created could be large, especially with a 16" wheel which rotates faster, so a dynamo hub intended for small-sized wheel could be more appropriate. But then again, most 16" bikes aren't ridden at 80 km/h, but full-sized road bikes may be in a mountain downhill road.
You just need to connect the rear light directly to the dynamo. With some electrical wiring skills, this can be done.

Interesting, thanks! So the rear lights will take the AC from a dynamo hub, too. I thought it was the front light only that did the magic of turning the AC to DC. Sounds like it should be pretty straightforward to just wire them in series, then. I have no worry that my speed -- even considering the small diameter wheel -- will ever be a problem :) The lacing might be a bit tough and I was a little concerned about the angle on the hub flanges, but I guess there won't be quite as much stress on it as there would be on a front wheel.

Don't wire in series, but in parallel. Otherwise, the switching power supplies in the two lights will interact in a weird way, and the lights might even have too little voltage to regulate correctly.

Thanks for the tip. My thinking was that wiring in series might go some way to counteracting the problem of too much power coming from the dynamo, but I didn't think about the fact that is would only halve the voltage. By now I guess it's clear I'm no electrician :)

"Should handle that" is still far away from "does handle that". I have toasted an LED backlight by running without a front light.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica It may be related to the quality of the backlight. If it has a power supply that can't handle the high voltages, it may be damaged. Of course it's a good question why would a reputable lightmaker make backlights that are damaged by voltages the dynamo can create. Switching to a different backlight may help.

Wiring in series might deal with too much voltage.  If you needed to deal with too much current parallel would share it out.

@juhist If you use a Zehner diode to keep the voltage in check (perfectly valid design), that zehner diode needs to be able to dissipate as much power as a headlight. That's not your typical surface mounted device, it requires waste heat management. If you tried to simply gate the input voltage into a buffer condensator, allowing the current to flow only for very short pulses, you'd get even higher voltage spikes when the gate transistor cuts the current. The dynamo has a significant impedance, after all. Of course, it can be done, but it's expensive and bulky, providing little benefit.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica In most Zener circuits most of the power is dissipated in a series resistor, and 20W (for example) resistors are easy, as are 5W zeners in both through-hole and SMD.  But anyway I don't think we'd be talking about SMD here, more like through-hole on stripboard

@ChrisH I've SMD circuitry in LED backlights, but never a backlight with nearly sufficiently beefy parts, though.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica I've tried to repair a B&M Secula rear light - SMD covered in lacquer.  But I was thinking about home-made custom circuits in the context of this question.  The beefier SMD zeners are rated on peak power dissipation (good luck speccing the duty cycle) but you can still get a few W DC in little packages

When we still all ran filament bulbs of a dynamo we learned fast to switch the dynamo off when the front light stopped working.
The front light took much more of the power and with just the rear light that one would burn out quickly.
So I am pretty sure your plan for a rear light only dynamo will need a lot of tricks to get it working.
If the wheel and the position of the rear light allow for it you can use a magnet driven light. Searching on magnet bike light I found some on internet, but only selling sites which I should not link to. With the ones I am familiar with you have one or more magnets in the wheel and the light, also with a magnet in it, close to the wheel.
An easier alternative might be to have two rechargeable battery driven lights and swap them at a regular basis, recharging as soon as it comes off. Or even have two side by side if neither is charging.
PS, looks like the trick is led lights. See the answer by @juhist.

Thanks for answering. I've used the magnet type lights before, but wasn't happy with how finicky they were. You seem to have to get them set up just right and with the amount of abuse the trailer gets I just know they're going to constantly be getting knocked out of wack. You're right, if juhist is right, LED seems to be just what I'm after. I currently use rechargeable lights and that's what I'm aiming to replace

An alternative suggestion: fit a front light to the trailer, but mount it underneath  pointing down at the road.
The light spilling out round the edges will help you be seen from the back and sides.  I'd consider some amber glass paint (translucent) on the lens, or red if most of the light comes out the back. Diffusing the light by lightly sanding the lens wouldn't be a bad idea.
But don't take a front light and point it straight backwards, even with a red filter.  It would be too bright for anyone in the direct beam.  If you're likely to have bikes close behind, a strong red light reflected of a wet road is still pretty dazzling in the dark.

A load resistor in parallel with the rear light(s)* would ensure that they don't receive too much current.  At the nominal 6V dynamo output you'd want to draw about 0.4A so by Ohm's law V=IR, 6=0.4R or 15Ω.  This should be sized to handle well over the nominal output power as the wheel will be spinning quite fast and dynamo output rises with speed.
With a 16" wheel I'd be tempted to add 2 Zener diodes of about 6-9V and a series resistor as shown here (section Square Wave Signal) to limit the voltage the rear light sees.

* I recommend 2 rear lights on the corners of a trailer

Thanks -- I certainly intend to have at least two lights on the back. I guess I could light it up like a Christmas tree with all of that "free" power :) I assume the SM-DH10 that Paul mentions below contain something akin to the Zener diodes you mention?

@Matt, yes. There's some technical debate here

If you use a dynamo, you need to use a front light to restrict the voltage. Without it, your back light might work at low speeds, but is very likely to burn once you get too fast.
Technical explanation
Dynamos are unregulated power sources. Without any load connected to them, their output voltage grows linearly with speed. And if they deliver 6V at 20km/h, they will output 24V at 80km/h. Much too much for 6V circuitry. However, they are meant to be used with the load of a front light, which corresponds to a certain current at 6V, and they are designed with an impedance that will counteract that rising voltage as long as this current is drawn. That is why filament based lights were safe to use at any speed. And only a front light can draw enough current to limit the voltage.
If you run a rear light on a dynamo without a front light, it does not put a sufficient load on the dynamo. The voltage will skyrocket, and unless the rear light has expensive power circuitry built in that is either capable of dealing with 5x the normal voltage, or contains a heating element that can dump the same power as a head light, it will burn out.
I learned this lesson the hard way when I toasted an LED backlight because my head light had failed and didn't provide the required energy sink (parallel connected lights).

As an alternative, you can use an overvoltage protector such as the Shimano SM-DH10. This will limit the voltage to about 9 volts, which any LED light should be able to deal with.

Actually, I think this is just what I'm looking for. Something that will limit the voltage. I just had a look at that part and I actually think I have one that came with a dynamo I had a while back. Just need to root through my tool cupboards to find it. Cheers for that!

Thanks cmaster... but the chances of me doing more than 20kph with the 50kg+ I carry in the trailer is slim -- I appreciate the warning, though -- that is what I was a bit worried about, to be honest.

@Matt Good for you. I wouldn't want to do high speeds with a heavy trailer either. Even though it could push you to even higher speeds on descends. 100kg bike + rider + 50kg trailer going downhill on a 10% slope at 72km/h would be 3kW or 4PS, after all. As a heavy rider, I always profited from this simple truth on my downhill rides :-) But I would never do it with a trailer for fear of loosing control.

@Matt also trailers aren't very aero, so even if you dropped something off and came home empty they make good air-brakes

@ChrisH I would think aero enough when they are filled with 50kg. It's a balance of force between aero drag and gravitational push. For each speed there is a certain load at which the gravitational push starts to exceed the drag.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica if you consider only  a downhill, yes (or rather, "for each speed and gradient").  But that's why I talked about coming home empty, when you might go faster based on safety considerations, but it wouldn't want to go very fast
